# How do I get people to realize that Google Voice asking for their name is not my voicemail?

Tags: google-voice

I realize this is somewhat tangential to the web application itself, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

I use the Google Voice call screening feature to ask callers to give their name when their number is not in my contacts (or is in certain groups, such as the one I have for recruiters). Unfortunately, a significant number of people don't actually listen to the message and assume that it's my voicemail, which makes one of two things happen:

1. They hang up and tell me later that their call just went to voicemail
2. They start off with "Hey, Adam, this is..." and the recording cuts off before they actually get to their **name**.

Is there anything that I can do to the message to make it more obvious that:

1. They should only state their name
2. This isn't voicemail and I'll likely answer in a ring or two.

Comment: People being deaf isn't quite a question right for this site. You'll have to bear with people who don't understand simple audio prompts

Comment: For what it's worth, I get the same thing and I feel your pain. Maybe when GV and its ilk are more widely used.